# Yii - getActiveFormWidget() returns wrong type in core?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cformmodel, yii-cform

**I am only trying to create a non-AJAX registration form.**

When I submit through a CForm, PHP says error() is being called on a non-object. I checked the source file where the error occurred and (using `var_dump(get_class($parent->getActiveFormWidget()));`) found that getActiveFormWidget() returns a `CFormInputElement`, which does not have error() defined.

I thought this had to do with [CForm::activeForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CForm#activeForm-detail), but it defaulted to `CActiveForm`.

I did try `'enableAjaxValidation'=>false`.

What am I not understanding? I suspect I misinterpreted something along the way.

***CFormInputElement::renderError():***

```
public function renderError()
{
    $parent=$this->getParent();

    // $parent->getActiveFormWidget() returns object that does not define error()

    return $parent->getActiveFormWidget()->error($parent->getModel(), $this->name, $this->errorOptions, $this->enableAjaxValidation, $this->enableClientValidation);
}
```

***Model:***

```
class RegisterFormModel extends CFormModel {

    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $password_confirm;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('email, password, password_confirm', 'required'),
            array('password','compare','compareAttribute'=>'password_confirm'),
            array('password, password_confirm','length','min'=>'6','max'=>'20'),
            array('email', 'email'),
            array('email', 'length', 'max'=>256)
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'email'=>'Email',
            'password'=>'Password',
            'password_confirm'=>'Confirm Password',
        );
    }
}
```

***View:***

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo $form; ?> 
</div><!-- form -->
```

***Controller Action:***

```
class RegisterAction extends CAction
{
    public function run()
    {
        $register_model = new RegisterFormModel;

        $controller = $this->getController();

        $form = new CForm(array(
            'title'=>'Register',
            'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
            'elements'=>array(
                'email'=>array(
                    'type'=>'text',
                    'maxlength'=>256,
                ),
                'password'=>array(
                    'type'=>'password',
                    'minlength'=>6,
                    'maxlength'=>32,
                ),
                'password_confirm'=>array(
                    'type'=>'password',
                    'minlength'=>6,
                    'maxlength'=>32,
                ),
            ),

            'buttons'=>array(
                'register'=>array(
                    'type'=>'submit',
                    'label'=>'Register',
                ),
            ),
        ), $register_model);

        if($form->submitted('register', true) && $form->validate())
        {
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            $controller->render('register', array('model'=>$register_model, 'form'=>$form));    
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for this error? Have you tried running it in a debugger to see where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have never seen using CForm as you show us.

I recommend you to use the active form widget,

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/195/implementing-a-registration-process-using-the-yii-user-management-module/

and you need to define all those fields in your CFormModel. This way you will be able to provide proper validation for them.

Comment: What's the difference between what I've shown and what is documented here? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder

Comment: That is a very old article it was posted in 2011 January. The disadvantage you will definitively  have is that you won't have power over layout and design. And it's not widely used, so less people can help you with that. You should more likely go with CFormModel or an Active Record approach.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the answer is really late :)
But for the sake of anyone else who may have a similar error.

```
<?php
 // change from: echo $form;
 echo $form->render();
?>
```

I was rendering the elements separately so this is how I did it:

```
<?php
 // without the renderBegin() and renderEnd() it may give the no object error
 echo $form->renderBegin();
 echo $form->renderElements();
 echo $form->renderEnd();
?>
```